# calculating the amount of months to reach a down payment

Tags: python, spyder

Write a script that includes the definition of house_loan() that you just wrote. When the script is executed, it should ask the user to enter the following values and then use the house_loan() function to calculate the months needed to save enough money for a down payment. Note that all the arguments needs to be float numbers.

1. The starting annual salary
2. The portion of salary to be saved
3. The cost of your dream home

```
Test Case #1
>>>
Enter your annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10
Enter the cost of your dream house: 1000000
Number of months: 183
>>>
```

```
Test Case #2 
>>>
Enter your annual salary: 80000
Enter the percent of your salary to save (as a decimal): .15
Enter the cost of your dream home: 500000
Number of months: 105
>>>
```

*When I execute my code, I either get a super high number or a number that's below it. I cannot figure out the right way to set up my code in order for it to pass the 1st and 2nd Case. Moreover, I just help in setting it up correctly, in order to get the correct answer.*

```
Code
annual_salary = float(input('What's your annual salary? \n'))
portion_saved = float(input('What portion would you like to save (as a decimal)? \n'))
portion_downpayment = 0.25
total_cost = float(input('What is the total cost of your dream house? \n'))

def house_loan(annual_salary,
               portion_saved,
               portion_downpayment,
               total_cost):

    cost_to_be_paid = total_cost - portion_downpayment    #calculat the pending money to be paid
    monthly_salary = annual_salary/12                     #calculate the monthly salary 
    monthly_savings = monthly_salary*portion_saved        #calculate monthly savings in salary 
    total_months = cost_to_be_paid/monthly_savings        #returning the months required to pay money

    return total_months 
print('The months required to pay enough money for the down payment is: ',house_loan(annual_salary, portion_saved, portion_downpayment, total_cost))
```

Comment: I think you're cost_to_be_paid should multiply instead of subtracting.

Comment: i changed it to multiplying, and it just gave me a bigger number

Comment: Please include the rest of the code (where you call `house_loan()` and display the result). You can also put in some `print()` statements to see where the calculation goes wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math issue, not a code problem. `monthly_savings` should be a division, and you should only be calculating months based on the amount down payment, not the total amount, according to the question

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I added the `print()` statement!

Comment: Please post the code you used to get your test results. The above code can't execute with syntax errors like you single quotes in `'What's your annual salary? \n'`. Also put a `print()` statement after calculation step and show your intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

Your portion_downpayment wasn't a global variable, so it never got passed into your function.  This works:

```
annual_salary = float(input('Whats your annual salary? \n'))
portion_saved = float(input('What portion would you like to save (as a decimal)? \n'))
total_cost = float(input('What is the total cost of your dream house? \n'))

def house_loan(annual_salary,
               portion_saved,
               portion_downpayment,
               total_cost):

    portion_downpayment = 0.25
    cost_to_be_paid = total_cost * portion_downpayment      #calculat the pending money to be paid
    monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12                     #calculate the monthly salary
    monthly_savings = monthly_salary * portion_saved        #calculate monthly savings in salary
    total_months = cost_to_be_paid / monthly_savings        #returning the months required to pay money
    return(total_months)

print('The months required to pay enough money for the down payment is: %s' % house_loan(annual_salary, portion_saved, portion_downpayment, total_cost))
```